# codeigniter gives error after turning off directory listing

Tags: apache, codeigniter, .htaccess

Well I have website in `codeIgniter` running on my server. Where I want to disable the directory listing for assets and other folders stored on server for security reasons. To do this I have created `.htaccess` file in  every directory for which I want to turn off listing.
In file I have written following code. which turn off the directory listing.

`Options -Indexes`

Now if I try to access the directory using url like following
`www.demo.com/assets`
It gives following error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Error' does not have a method 'index'

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 532
```

Here, `assets` folder contains the .htaccess file.
Instead of showing this error, I want to show an access denied or some appropriate message.
Also I want to know is it okay to turn off directory listing for folders which are used by codeIgniter like assets folder contains `javascript,css etc`
Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a `.htaccess` for each folder, you can take CodeIgniter's approach by creating a `index.html` in each folder instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Upon attempting to visit the directory, the user will receive the forbidden message, and functionality will not be affected.